# The value ' 'is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am a but new here and learning programming with XML ......I have created a function which upload xml file ...on upload xml (which is simple question and answer data with user data) and validating function throws an Exception...

> e.Message = "The 'id' element is invalid - The value '43516' is
>   invalid according to its datatype
>   '[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:short](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema%3ashort)' - The string '43516' is not a
>   valid Int16 value."

this is my function

```
  [WebMethod]
            public static bool CheckFile(string filename)
            {

                    surgeProtection = true;
                    bool returnval = false;
                    String xsdPath = "";
                    //Read the path to upload on the web server
                    string Uploadpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"];
                    xsdPath = Uploadpath + "\\" + "survey.xsd";

                    ////Validate the uploaded files on the web server

                    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet(); //intialize schema class
                    using (FileStream schemastream = File.OpenRead(xsdPath)) //xsd file load
                    {
                        schemas.Add(XmlSchema.Read(schemastream, new ValidationEventHandler(OnValidate)));
                            //create event for schema
                    }
                    schemas.Compile();

                    String xmlPath = filename;
                    xmlPath = Uploadpath + "\\" + filename;


                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                     byte[] mybyte = Dashboard.Model.Surveys.SurveyService.GetImageFromDB(filename);
                    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mybyte);
                    doc.LoadXml(xml);


                    doc.Schemas = schemas; // take schema
                    doc.Validate(OnValidate); // validate schema

                    returnval = surgeProtection;
                    return returnval;

                }



This is my validation Function

        public static void OnValidate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
            {

         switch (e.Severity)
            {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:

                    surgeProtection = false;
                    sw.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
            }

this is my xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <survey>
        <title>xxxxxxxxxx</title>
        <questions>
            <question>
                <description>TestDescription</description>
                <type>grid</type>
                <id>43516</id>
                <options>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </options>
                <sub-question description="-" id="43516_01">
                    <response>
                        <answer user="xxxx@xxx.com">7</answer>

                    </response>
                </sub-question>
            </question>
        ..and so on questions
        </questions>
        <users>
            <user iRecipientId="" sEmail="xxxx" city="xx" country="xx" responseDate="xxx"/>

        ..and so on
        </users>
    </survey>
```

this is my table design in DB

```
ID          int         Unchecked
ImageName   varchar(200)    Unchecked
Image   varbinary(MAX)  Unchecked
```

XML is very big ...But I have just shown the basic format ... I have understood that ptoblem is with the column 43516 abd suqestion   ...

What data type I need to assign then and where Do I need to change the datatype ??.Do I need to change at the DB Table ?  in SQL datatype is int or bigint ...not short ..long ..do I need to change to bigint ?
Any suggestion would e Helpful

Comment: this error reslved ...there is element in schema  <xs:element type="xs:int" name="id"/> ...which  is showing error ...I change change that to "long" that error resolved ...but another error comes ..."The 'id' attribute is not declared." ...where do I need to change "id" more ?

Answer (score 1):

Check what id is defined in your schema. I guess it will be defined as short, and you need to change that to int. Or alternatively use an id value that is in the short range.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719879(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719879%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I got these warnings when I upgraded my Visual Studio 2005 Project to VS2010.

Warning 1   The 'IsAppSettingsProperty' attribute is invalid - The value 'False' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:boolean' - The string 'False' is not a valid Boolean value.

When I looked at the XMLSxhema per the URL listed above, I found that the True | False is case sensitive. I replaced those warning location booleans with all lower case true | false. The warnings are all gone.